# attach github master branch to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried **AWS CodeDeploy** but its not showing my application in existing resources.

What i want to do is when anything pushed to master branch on my github then it should directly deployed to Elastic Beanstalk. i have seen third party tools for this but is it possible just between GitHub and Aws Elastic Beanstalk?

PS : not looking for this http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git